# How can I use openGL to draw a graph based on the values of a texture?

Tags: opengl

I want to take an RGB texture, convert it to YUV and draw a graph based on the UV components of each pixel, essentially, a vectorscope (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorscope).

I have no problem getting openGL to convert the texture to YUV in a fragment shader and even to draw the texture itself (even if it looks goofy because it is in YUV color space), but beyond that I am at a bit of a loss. Since I'm basically drawing a line from one UV coord to the next, using a fragment shader seems horribly inefficient (lots of discarded fragments).

I just don't know enough about what I can do with openGL to know what my next step is. I did do a CPU rendered version that I discarded since it simply wasn't fast enough (100ms for a single 1080p frame). My source image updates at up to 60fps.

Just for clarity, I am currently using openTK. Any help nudging me in a workable direction is very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe reframe your question to purely graphics, the number of people knowing what YUV and vectorscope are in addition to OpenGL is probably in the single digits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image you want a graph of is the texture, I suggest two steps.

First step, convert the RGB texture to YUV which you've done. Render this to an offscreen framebuffer/texture target instead of a window so you have the YUV texture map for the next step.

Second step, draw a line W x H times, ie once for each pixel in the texture. Use instanced rendering, one line N times, rather than actually creating geometry for them all, because the coordinates for the ends of the line will be dummies.

In the vertex shader, gl_InstanceID will be the number of this line from 0 to N - 1. Convert to 2D texture coords for the pixel in the YUV texture that you want to graph. I've never written a vectorscope myself, but presumably you know how to convert this YUV color you get from the texture into 2D/3D coords.